# estimate of measure of a $C^1$ range set

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and
> $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ function . Denote
> $J_f(x)=\det(f'(x))$ . Prove that $$\mu(f(X))\leq\int_X|J_f(x)|dx$$
> for any $X\subset\Omega$ and $\mu$ as the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ .

This is easily verified by [Sard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem) . A basic proof of Sard's theorem uses the technique by dividing the set $X$ into hypercubes and on each hypercube $f'$ is uniformly continuous , and therefore we can estimate (using MVT) the measure of $f(X)$ . But exactly the proof doesn't fulfill the requirement on RHS appearing as the integral . Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be measurable. The change of variables formula, Theorem 3.9 on page 122 of "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions by Evans and Gariepy, yields
$$\int_{A}|Jf(x)|\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} 1_A(x)|Jf(x)|\,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)}1_A(x)\,dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\#(f^{-1}(y) \cap A)\,dy.$$
Meanwhile,
$$\mu(f(A)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}I(f^{-1}(y) \cap A \neq \emptyset)\,dy.$$
So $\mu(f(A)) \leq \int_{A}|Jf(x)|\,dx$.